# Pass and render some value only on the first item from a parent model of collection type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My issue here involves the `HtmlHelper.DisplayFor`, this accepts an additional view data which I can use to pass some value to the display template view.
However if the parent page's model (the page containing the `Html.DisplayFor`) is a collection, I would like to just pass the value for the first item (each one rendered by a display template) only. Something like this:

**The display template**:

```
@* This is saved as a file named ItemModelTemplate.cshtml *@
@model ItemModel
@{
   var a = ViewData["a"] as string;
}    
<div>@(a == null ? "" : a)</div>
```

**The parent view**:

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemModel>
@{
    var firstItem = Model.FirstOrDefault();
    if(firstItem != null){
        Html.DisplayFor(e => firstItem, "ItemModelTemplate", new { a = "123" });
    }
}
@foreach(var item in Model.Skip(1)){
    @Html.DisplayFor(e => item, "ItemModelTemplate")
}
```

Please note that I would like to save template file using a custom name (not following the naming convention which should match the item model type name).

The above code renders **all** the items with `123` wrapped inside. I understand that the `ViewData` always contains the key `a` paired with value `123` once set. I need to somehow clear that value **after** the first item picking the value out of the ViewData. But looks like that's not easy with how the razor view works. Here is one of my attempts, this however will clear the value and even the first item won't catch it:

```
if(firstItem != null){
    Html.DisplayFor(e => item, "ItemModelTemplate", new { a = "123" });
    //try clearing the value
    ViewContext.Controller.ViewData.Remove("a");        
}
```

The result is all the items rendered without any value wrapped inside (meaning "123" is not passed to any).
I've even used `ViewContext.ViewData.Remove("a")` but it has no effect at all.

I've played around with ASP.NET for long enough to build simple websites, but sometimes something like this always puzzles me and really I cannot solve this myself easily. I hope someone here has encountered this scenario before and successfully dealt with it and can share with me the solutions. Thanks a lot!